# Unable to get variable's value from another class C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to print the information of candidates using Crystal Report.

The candidate_id is placed in **candidate class**, what i want is to get this id in my Report class to print CrystalReport against that `candidate_id`.

Following is my Code for candidate class

```
public partial class Candidate : System.Web.UI.Page {
    string candidate_id;         
    public String CandId {
        get { return candidate_id; }
        set { 
            //getting id stored in session and setting its value
            candidate_id = Convert.ToString(Session["candidate_id_in_session"]); 
        }
    }
```

Here is my **Report Class** where i am trying to get **candidate_id**

```
public class Report {    
    public static DataSet LoadReport() {
        string candidate_val;            
        Candidate can = new Candidate();
        candidate_val = can.CandId;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT * From personal_information " + 
            "WHERE candidateNo = @candidate_val", myConn
        );

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@candidate_val",candidate_val);
        da.SelectCommand = command;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "personal_information");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

and i am getting following exception which clearly means that i am not getting `candidate_id` from the other class.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The parameterized query '(@ nvarchar(4000))SELECT * From personal_information WHERE c' expects the parameter '@candidate_val', which was not supplied.
```

Please tell me where am i doing wrong?

I have checked the value is getting set in the setter but not returning in getter, and other interesting thing is that if i return hard-coded value in getter then it gets passed to the other class.

Comment: Is the setter ever called? It's not called automatically... You actually need to call it!

Comment: why should i call setter explicitly ? when it is getting called when i made the object of the class and called its method.
`Candidate can = new Candidate();`
`candidate_val = can.CandId;`

Comment: @user3349973 Did you read my answer? I guess your property is implemented wrong. If you want to *get*  a value from the session through a property, it makes no sense to *set*  the property, but the *getter*  should be implemented accordingly!

Comment: @user3349973 property setters are NOT automatically called when you create an object. Your property setter is never called, so candidate_id is always null.

Comment: @Sajjad No, that's wrong. A property's setter is not called unless you explicitly use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provide a `null` value in this line:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@candidate_val",candidate_val);
```

because you set `candidate_val` like this:

```
Candidate can = new Candidate();
candidate_val = can.CandId;
```

And in a freshly created `Candidate`, without having set `CandId`, the value of `CandId` is `null`.

Also the implementation of the `CandId` property is somewhat strange. I'd implement it like this:

```
public String CandId {
    get { return Convert.ToString(Session["candidate_id_in_session"]; }
    set { Session["candidate_id_in_session"] = value; }
}
```

Otherwise you have to call `CandId = <any value you want>` to get the value from the session into the `CandId` property - how logical is that?

As a programmer I'd expect the property to return the current value and upon setting, change the current value, which is not what your implementation does.

---

Because it was mentioned in the comments: To set the parameter to `DBNull` explicitly, you'd need something like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@candidate_val",candidate_val ?? DBNull.Value);
```

---

Just to make it clearer: I think it is **really bad style** the implement the property like this! If i call

```
CandId = "Hello";
```

I expect the property to have the value "Hello" and not something else, as it is in your case!

---

From the comment I get you don't even want to set the property. Then you should modify it like this:

```
public String CandId {
    get { return Convert.ToString(Session["candidate_id_in_session"]; }
}
```

---

**Final edit**

The design you're implementing is not very well planned. The class `Report` is actually independent of anything UI/web/interaction related, but a pure business logic class. In fact it doesn't even matter whether you use this class in an ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF or Windows Service project. Why do you introduce a dependency by making it access the ASP.NET session? There's no reason for this, and it shouldn't be done (just like the business logic should not display error messages).

You should change the methods so they take the values they need as parameters (and while you're at it, free resources properly):

```
public class Report {    
    public static DataSet LoadReport(string candidate_val) {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From personal_information WHERE candidateNo = @candidate_val", myConn))
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@candidate_val",candidate_val);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "personal_information");
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

If that is done, your problems will be gone by simply invoking the `LoadReport` function as:

```
DataSet ds = Report.LoadReport(Convert.ToString(Session["candidate_id_in_session"]));
```

Comment: correct which you need to set the SqlParameter to DBNull.Value (IF you wanted to pass a null value to the DB of course)

Comment: Than you for your detail reply. Let me clarify things a bit more.
the `candidate_id` is already in the session somewhere. Now in order to get it, i do not need to set it again in the setter as i have already set it somewhere( i do not want to override session value by setting it again). what if i remove the setter and return the the session value.something like this

`public String CandId{

string 

value=Convert.ToString(Session["candidate_id_in_session"];
 get{return value}
}`

Comment: That would even be the cleanest solution. However, you can not write it like that. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: one more unusual thing for me is that by hard-coding the value in getter

`get{ return "123415"}`

it becomes readily available in next class.

Comment: That's not unusual at all. If your session does not contain the value you don't get a result. What's the "next class"?

Comment: the thing is session do contains value but it is not getting passed to the Report Class, by next class i mean the `Report` class.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer in a minute to point out a possible solution.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar- Great! thank you.Problem solved. I should have considered that at the first place instead of using ASP.NET session.

Answer (score 0):

An important note to address:

You cannot assign value like the following in the `Setter`:

```
candidate_id = Convert.ToString(Session["candidate_id_in_session"]);
```

Rather write it as:

```
public partial class Candidate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string candidate_val; 
    public String CandId {
        get { return candidate_id; }
        set { candidate_id = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, you are trying to get the id stored in session. Then you can directly use the session variable as:

```
public partial class Candidate : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
    public String CandId {
        get { return Convert.ToString(Session["candidate_id_in_session"]); }
        set { Session["candidate_id_in_session"] = value; }
    }
}
```